# How to handle the high data rate of fluorescence microscopy camera?

Tags: java, rate

I have a question how I can learn to handle (with perhaps java) high data rates. My task is:

I will have a fluorescence microscopy camera with around 1Gigabyte/s and number of images between 100/s and 1000/s. 
The image data should be written uncompressed as raw data on the disk. The storage system is not yet decided and should be dimensioned based on the needed performance. During the data acquisition a more or less live image should be shown.

Has somebody some suggestions for books or lecture notes for me?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty open ended, but I can give you advice based upon my past experience building multi-camera, real time data acquisition systems.

Typically these data acquisition systems require (though you may have to purchase it separately) a video capture card. the cards typically buffer some number of frames and the frame rate you can support depends on home long you need to run the acquisition system and the slowest data transfer rate in the "camera->capture card->hard drive" chain. These cards typically come with a documented API (typically in a C variant, I've never seen a Java variant but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist) and libraries that you can compile against that support code using the documented API functions to record data to storage.

When I have worked on systems that just needed a full motion video frame rate (~ 30 Hz) a windows box with a capture card has sufficed just fine. I am pretty sure you can get cards that will sample in the 1kHz range or higher (depending on your camera resolution), but you may be limited on the duration you can sample (given the limited available storage) during the acquisition process if you are sampling data faster than the buffer can clear it to final storage.

Also there is no reason for you to display >30 Hz at one time, no display system is going to support a 1kHz refresh rate, and the human eye can't process >30 Hz anyway.

Unfortunately in my experience these systems are put together piece meal because they are highly specialized which limits the market and disincentivies a standardized approach. The bottom line is that you are probably looking at either using a capture card manufacturer provided API interface (I'd advocate against wrapping it in JAVA because you'll just be adding extra latency that you can't afford at the acquisition rates you are talking about) or having an Electrical Engineer custom fit your solution. If I were in your shoes, I'd be searching for a capture card that meets my requirements, perhaps from the microscopy camera manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunatly this camera is a self made system from a past student. The software of the video capture cards only delivers the data stream. The ccd consists of 4 parts so I have 4 video cards. In the DAQ computer system I have to put the image parts again together.

Comment: Of course I want to show the sample image only with ~30Hz =)                           I thought Java would perhaps be ok for this system but I can also go for C++.                               Perhaps you know some books or lectures where I can read about this?

Comment: C++ is what I would do. honestly, the best way to figure this out is trial and error. Home brew systems just have too many warts, though I am happy to point you in the right direction. Am I to understand that you have 4 frame grabber cards pulling the data and successfully recording the data and you just need to know how to reliably recombine them? or are you looking for a solution to record the data? Also are you in an academic setting or commercial? Student makes me think academic and may make your solution easier

Comment: The programming is part of my PhD so yes it can be a more academic solution. - Yes there will be 4 frame grabber cards. The task is now to record the data and also show during acquisition an image.

Comment: what about the other question? Are you currently recording the data and just need to be able to synch everything together, or are you in need of a way to record the data at a successful I/O rate?  I get that you have 4 cards, but want to know whether or not they are writing the data to storage quickly enough for your data I/O.

Comment: Currently I have an old system with 2 old frame grapper cards at a much lower speed rate. This works fine but the data rate is only 30MByte/s. The data first goes in an ring-buffer and then is recorded on the disk. I am not sure if this concept would work with 1GByte/s also I cannot get all the source code to adapt it with the new system.

Comment: without a good handle on your system and some testing I can't tell you exactly what model of this or that to use, but I can tell you what I would do in your situation. I would get 4 new digital frame grabber cards that can hand the camera resolution at 1kHz (or your fastest desired speed) and that have an external hardware signal trigger. and I would hook one up to each camera. I would then trigger the cards through a distribution box so that they all fire at the same time.as long as you can offload data before the buffer fills you'll be ok. also make friends with an EE PhD candidate to help.